# String.getBytes("8bit encoding") returns 2 bytes per symbol

Tags: java, string, encoding, character-encoding, windows-1251

I'm trying to understand character encoding for Strings in Java. I'm working on Windows 10 and the default character encoding is `windows-1251`. it is 8-bit encoding character. So it must be 1 byte for 1 symbol. So when I call `getBytes()` for a String with 6 symbols, I expect an array of 6 bytes. But the following code snippet returns 12, instead of 6.

```
"Привет".getBytes("windows-1251").length // returns 12
```

At first, I thought that the first byte of the character must be zero. But both bytes related to the character have non-zero values. Could anyone explain, what I'm missing here, please?

Here is an example of how I tested it

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HexFormat;

public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().displayName());
        String s = "Привет";
        System.out.println("bytes count in windows-1251: " + s.getBytes("windows-1251").length);
        printBytes(s.getBytes("windows-1251"), "windows-1251");
    }
    
    public static void printBytes(byte[] array, String name) {
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
            System.out.println(name + "[" + k + "] = " + "0x" +
                byteToHex(array[k]));
        }
    }

static public String byteToHex(byte b) {
      // Returns hex String representation of byte b
      char hexDigit[] = {
         '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
         '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
      };
      char[] array = { hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f] };
      return new String(array);
   }
}
```

the result is:

```
windows-1251
bytes count in windows-1251: 12
windows-1251[0] = 0xd0
windows-1251[1] = 0x9f
windows-1251[2] = 0xd1
windows-1251[3] = 0x80
windows-1251[4] = 0xd0
windows-1251[5] = 0xb8
windows-1251[6] = 0xd0
windows-1251[7] = 0xb2
windows-1251[8] = 0xd0
windows-1251[9] = 0xb5
windows-1251[10] = 0xd1
windows-1251[11] = 0x82
```

but what I expect is:

```
windows-1251
bytes count in windows-1251: 6
windows-1251[0] = 0xcf
windows-1251[1] = 0xf0
windows-1251[2] = 0xe8
windows-1251[3] = 0xe2
windows-1251[4] = 0xe5
windows-1251[5] = 0xf2
```

Comment: Very strange: on my machine this works without problem and yields the expected output. Also running it in an online IDE like https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/ also gives the expected output.

Comment: Note that `HexFormat.of().withDelimiter(", ").formatHex("Привет".getBytes("UTF-8"))` is `d0, 9f, d1, 80, d0, b8, d0, b2, d0, b5, d1, 82`, perhaps you have compiled with source file of different encoding to windows-1251

Comment: For some reason it looks like your vm cannot decode Windows-1251. It's essentially ignored and you get UTF-8. btw if you import `HexFormat` why do you do so much work? ;)

Comment: [Can not reproduce](https://tio.run/##fVDLasMwELznKxaBQSaOSAK9NO2lpcf2kmPIQbFlR7EjGWudxJRA6Y/0HwqFfobzRa78CDGlqS6LdndmZ2bDd3y0CeKq8hNuDDxzqeB1APal@SqRPhjkaMtOywC2dkrnmEkVLZbAs8i4gOtM7w08HXyRotRndP3mhUGxZTpHlloMJopu7D2mpGb@mmdGIHvsaiBCnifYfanLAmnShBcvfCuo684upM15MHAPpPw4vZXf5Wf5dXons//uklWBwoCvc4VgLe6lCqzs0WR6M7kFAkMwLBL4UG9R0p8SlyVCRbjuaWhY293rMA9@NVr8cXAt3R5rrbZJOOOFd7asbBRuL95QZ0AtBGKbxXhmy12L6ATbznDYB/yVTUiJYxZOsKw5Ds54enAU8ZpbHsReS7iIlz33x87Hsap@AA). You should ensure that you source file has the right encoding (and the compiler options matched). Try to verify with `System.out.println(s);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like perhaps you have UTF-8 encoded source file when you compiled?

```
HexFormat.of().withPrefix(", ").formatHex("Привет".getBytes("UTF-8"))
==> "d09fd180d0b8d0b2d0b5d182"
```

If I save your code in my UTF-8 editor and compile+run:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Foo.java
UTF-8
bytes count in windows-1251: 6
windows-1251[0] = 0xcf
windows-1251[1] = 0xf0
windows-1251[2] = 0xe8
windows-1251[3] = 0xe2
windows-1251[4] = 0xe5
windows-1251[5] = 0xf2
```

Whereas this matches your output if compile+run that UTF8 file with your default encoding:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 Foo.java
windows-1251
bytes count in windows-1251: 12
windows-1251[0] = 0xd0
windows-1251[1] = 0x9f
windows-1251[2] = 0xd1
windows-1251[3] = 0x80
windows-1251[4] = 0xd0
windows-1251[5] = 0xb8
windows-1251[6] = 0xd0
windows-1251[7] = 0xb2
windows-1251[8] = 0xd0
windows-1251[9] = 0xb5
windows-1251[10] = 0xd1
windows-1251[11] = 0x82
```

If I change my editor charset to windows-1251 then the output is as expected:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 Foo.java
windows-1251
bytes count in windows-1251: 6
windows-1251[0] = 0xcf
windows-1251[1] = 0xf0
windows-1251[2] = 0xe8
windows-1251[3] = 0xe2
windows-1251[4] = 0xe5
windows-1251[5] = 0xf2
```

**EDIT**

For simplicity above I've used `java Foo.java` "compile and launch" mode but for normal separate use the important steps are to match up `javac` with character encoding of the source code, and `java` with any encoding you want the app to use:

```
javac -Dfile.encoding=TheJavaFilesCharSet {JavaFiles}
java  -Dfile.encoding=AnyOrDefaultCharSet {ClassWithMain}
```

As mentioned in the comments its worth using `HexFormat`, it is immutable and therefore safe to assign to a static field directly or via a user-friendly debugging output method:

```
private static final HexFormat HEX = HexFormat.ofDelimiter(", ").withPrefix("0x").withUpperCase();
public static String formatHex(byte[] arr) {
    return "new byte[/*"+arr.length+"*/] {"+HEX.formatHex(arr)+"}";
}

HEX.formatHex(new byte[]{1,2,3});
==> "0x01, 0x02, 0x03"

formatHex(new byte[]{1,2,3});
==> "new byte[/*3*/] {0x01, 0x02, 0x03}"
```

The latter is helpful if you want to cut/paste definitions back into testcases.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I also changed my java file encoding and it worked as expected. Thank you a lot. This shows me how encoding is complicated. When we initialize a variable in code, the value depends on encoding of source(compiled) file as well. I thought, since the variable is initialized and handled by jvm it will take care of everything. Of course, having hardcoded non latin value in code is a bad practice